# Permission denied while running azure databricks notebook as job scheduler

Tags: jobs, azure-databricks

I am trying to run a job scheduler in azure databricks. While its running various notebook, its failing and showing below error.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the jobs access control enabled in the workspace? Seems like you do not have permissions to run the job. Can please check first if this is enabled for your workspace, see here how to do so: https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/access-control/jobs-acl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @[santoznma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3734550/santoznma) in comment, you don’t have jobs access control enabled.

Enabling access control for jobs allows job owners to control who can view job results or manage runs of a job.

To enable it follow below steps:

**1.**  Go to the Admin Console.

**2.**  Click the Workspace Settings tab.

[image]

**3.**  Click the Cluster, Pool and Jobs Access Control toggle.

[image]

**4.**  Click Confirm.

Refer - [Enable jobs access control for your workspace - Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/access-control/jobs-acl#enable-jobs-access-control)

Comment: Thank you. Actually, for me, it is showing this feature to enable only work if I have a premium version but I have the standard version.

Comment: It did not worked for me. I tested enabling and disabling the option and also with single-node cluster and did not work. I think it is an issue of Databricks. In my case we're using DB in GCP.